# How to create custom modules app in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zeitwerk

I am newbie in rails, then i started try api only app. I want to try modular app like this structure:

```
├── app
│   ├── channels
│   │   └── application_cable
│   │       ├── channel.rb
│   │       └── connection.rb
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── application_controller.rb
│   │   └── concerns
│   ├── jobs
│   │   └── application_job.rb
│   ├── mailers
│   │   └── application_mailer.rb
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── application_record.rb
│   │   └── concerns
│   ├── users
│   │   ├── controllers
│   │   │   └── auth_controller.rb
│   │   ├── models
│   │   │   └── user_model.rb
│   │   ├── routes
│   │   │   └── user_routes.rb
│   │   ├── schema
│   │   │   └── request
│   │   │       └── auth_request.rb
│   │   └── usecase
│   │       └── auth_usecase.rb
```

but I have trouble with these structure which my `auth_controller.rb` cant mapping to route I create. below list the code:

auth_controller.rb

```
module Users
  class AuthController < ActionController::API
    def login
      body = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

      login_request = LoginRequest.new(body[:email],body[:password])
      if login_request.valid?

      else
        render json: { error: 'email or password can\'t be empty' }, status: :bad_request
      end

    rescue JSON::ParserError
      render json: { error: 'Invalid JSON format' }, status: :bad_request
    end
  end
end
```

user_model.rb

```
module Users
    class UserModel < ApplicationRecord
      this.table_name = "users"

      def create_user(users)
        save(users)
      end

      def find_user_by_id(id)
      end

      def find_user_by_email_password(email, password)
      end
    end
end
```

user_routes.rb

```
module Users
  module Routes
    def self.draw
      Rails.application.routes.draw do
        namespace :users do
            post 'auth/login', to: 'auth#login'
            post 'auth/register', to: 'auth#register'
            post 'auth/reset-password', to: 'auth#reset_password'
            post 'auth/send-otp', to: 'auth#send_otp'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

auth_request.rb

```
module Users
  module Schema
    module Request
      LoginRequest = Struct.new(:email,:password) do
        def valid?
          valid_email? && password.present?
        end
      end

      RegisterRequest = Struct.new(:first_name,:last_name,:email,:password,:phone) do
        def valid?
          first_name.present? && last_name.present? && valid_email? && password.present? && phone.present?
        end

        def valid_email?
          email =~ /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

auth_usecase.rb

```
module Users
  module Usecase
    class AuthUsecase
      def initialize(user_model)
        @user_model = user_model
      end

      def login(email, password)
        _ = user_model.find_user_by_email_password(email,password)
      end

      def register(user)
        user = user_model.create_user(user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # users routing /v1/users/*
  require_relative '../app/users/routes/user_routes'
  Users::Routes.draw

  # Reveal health status on /up that returns 200 if the app boots with no exceptions, otherwise 500.
  # Can be used by load balancers and uptime monitors to verify that the app is live.
  get "up" => "rails/health#show", as: :rails_health_check

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "posts#index"
end
```

I always get error like this

```
{
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "exception": "#<ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant Users::AuthController>",
    "traces": {
        "Application Trace": [],
        "Framework Trace": [],
        "Full Trace": []
    }
}
```

can you help me who to solve these error ? and should I make module name controllers inside controllers folder ? I am using Rails 7.1.2

Comment: Ruby on Rails is a very opinionated framework. And most of its “magic” only works when you follow its convention over configuration principal. While it would be possible to re-configure its default folder structure manually or by using engines or gems, it is certainly not recommended to try that for a “newbie”. I suggest following the Rails' way when you are still learning it and not try to fight its principals before you really understood them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this, but it could be useful to learn how autoloading works in rails:

```rb
app/
└── users/
    ├── controllers/
    │   └── auth_controller.rb
    ├── models/
    │   └── user_model.rb
    └── schema/
        └── request/
            └── auth_request.rb
```

```rb
# config/application.rb

Users = Module.new
Rails.autoloaders.main.push_dir(Rails.root.join("app/users"), namespace: Users)
Rails.autoloaders.main.collapse(Rails.root.join("app/users/controllers"))
Rails.autoloaders.main.collapse(Rails.root.join("app/users/models"))
```

You still have to follow some structure here when defining your constants. `models` and `controllers` directories are [collapsed](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk?tab=readme-ov-file#collapsing-directories) so you don't need a corresponding constant for them:

```rb
# app/users/controllers/user_controller.rb
module Users
  class AuthController
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/users/models/user_model.rb
module Users
  class UserModel
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/users/schema/request/auth_request.rb
module Users
  module Schema
    module Request
      module AuthRequest
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Test:

```rb
>> Users::AuthController
=> Users::AuthController
>> Users::UserModel
=> Users::UserModel
>> Users::Schema::Request::AuthRequest
=> Users::Schema::Request::AuthRequest
```

*https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk*

---

For your routes, there is `draw` method to split `routes.rb` into multiple files:
*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-draw*

Comment: maybe you just want an engine https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Comment: Please, don't post private APIs in public forums! A method whose name starts with two underscores and it is not documented is obviously not public interface.

Comment: thank you! If you'd like to refine even more, `push_dir` accepts pathnames also, that is uniform in all public API, both strings and pathnames work. So, you can save the `to_s` call if you wish.